# Map through an array of objects in js/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need an array of `alt` strings. I can map the array with `name` strings, but can't get it to return the "alt". This is what I tried:

```
const data = [
  { name: "Apple", alt: "Fruit" },
  { name: "Banana", alt: "Fruit" },
  { name: "Potatoe", alt: "Vegetable" },
  { name: "Lentil", alt: "Legume" }];
```

```
  <span>
      {data.map(item => {
        return (
         <Button item={item.alt.toUpperCase()}>
         {item}
         </Button>
         );
       })}
  </span>
```

To get an array of `name`strings, this worked:

```
  <span>
      {data.map(item => {
        return (
         <Button key={item.name} item={item.name.toUpperCase()}>
         {item}
         </Button>
         );
       })}
  </span>
```

This is the error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Comment: Is the data being populated from AJAX?

Comment: you are returning `{item}` inside button, which is an object. Either return `{item.name}` or `{item.alt}`

Comment: `item.alt` seems undefined in some places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to create a button please look below

The below code is modified to use key in map function as each of your record is unique and  react keys are useful when working with dynamically created components or when your data are altered . Setting the key value will keep your components uniquely identified after the change and they also help in performance.You can read the below blog it explains well about using keys.
**https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/why-do-i-need-keys-in-react-lists/**

```
 const data = [
      {id:1, name: "Apple", alt: "Fruit" },
      {id:2 ,name: "Banana", alt: "Fruit" },
      {id:3, name: "Potatoe", alt: "Vegetable" },
      {id:4, name: "Lentil", alt: "Legume" }
    ];
    function App() {
      return (
        <span>
          {data.map((item) => (
            <button key={item.id}>{item.alt.toUpperCase()}</button>
          ))}
        </span>
      );
    }
```

Use this link it is working here
*https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-wave-t117u*

Comment: This is exactly what I need! But I still get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined...

Comment: Hi Mina ,
Could you open the codesandbox and check.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<span>{
  data.map(
    (item, index) => <button 
      alt={item.alt.toUpperCase()} 
      key={someKeyHere}>
        {item.alt.toUpperCase()}
      </button>)
}</span>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kxpjm3?file=index.js) for your ref.